# RequiredIf Conditional Validation Core

Tags: asp.net-core

I'm trying to use requiredif in my asp.net core project however it gives error, I added the package, and when I use it, the page does not open, it returns several errors. I can not use it in core?

```
[Display(Name = "Inscrição Isento")]
        public bool InscricaoIsento { get; set; }
        [RequiredIf("InscricaoIsento", "false", ErrorMessage = "O campo Inscrição Estadual deve ser preenchido corretamente.")]
        [Display(Name = "Insc. Estadual")]
        public string InscricaoEstadual { get; set; }
```

Comment: What errors does it return? It's not clear what your problem here is. Please update your question

Comment: `Requiredif` is not a built-in attribute, which third party library are you using? In the older MVC framework you can use [MVC Foolproof Validation](https://foolproof.codeplex.com/), but I assume it is not avaible in ASP.Net Core

Comment: I tried to use FoolProof however when I try to use it it returns me several errors, what is the best way to do then the required? Without being through this library?

Comment: `RequiredIf` is not yet available in ASP.net core so you will need a library.The MVC Foolproof Validation isn't also not supporting ASP.net core, check [this](https://github.com/leniel/foolproof/issues/10) issue. So it will be interesting to see the errors.